# Using If/else statement to value according to slider value

Tags: javascript, html, model-view-controller

I am trying to change how value displayed using slider. I have made a label that display the value as below.

Course Duration : 1 day

the value displayed in here is changing according to the slider value.

so, when the slider value is in 1, it should be displayed as "day" and when the slider value greater than 1, it should be displayed as "days".

I have used if/else statement within my javascript to change the name displayed according to the slider value. The coding I used as below.

JS file :

```
// method used to get value from slider and display. 

function slider_value() {

    var slider = document.getElementById("myRange");
    var output = document.getElementById("demo");

    output.innerHTML = slider.value;

    slider.oninput = function () {
        output.innerHTML = this.value;
    }
}

// method used to change name according to slider value

function value_name() {

    var count = document.getElementById("myRange");
    var outname = document.getElementById("dname"); 

    if (parseInt(count.value) == 1) {
        outname.innerHTML = "Day";
    }
    else {
        outname.innerHTML = "Days";
    }
}
```

HTML file:

```
<label for="duration">

    Course Duration :

    <span id="demo"></span>
    <span id="dname"></span>

</label>

<div class="slidecontainer">

    <input type="range" min="1" max="15" value="1" class="slider" id="myRange">

</div>
```

I have called the functions to the view as below:

```
<script> 
    slider_value();
    value_name();
</script>
```

Coding won't show any errors while debugging but it only shows day or days and won't change according to the slider value. so I am expecting some help and ideas to rectify this.

Thanks a bunch.

Comment: Where, when and how are you calling `value_name` function? The function call can't be seen in the body of the input handler, where it should be, to reflect changes in the slider value to the span element.

Comment: `slider.oninput = function () { output.innerHTML = this.value; }`. This code, to update the label, does not check if the name should change as well. So you should call `value_name();` somewhere here. But since they both overwrite the innerHTML, you need to change one of those functions so they can work together instead of fight over the innerHTML of the same label.

Comment: I have inserted the whole code for the view at the question. can you check the code and give me some answers???

Comment: @MalakaAttanayake But you already have got two of them ..?

Comment: Change `value_name()` to return you the name string instead of update the labels innerHTML directly. That way you can call `value_name()` both at the start and inside the onchange event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the oninput and onchange events of the input element, such as:
`oninput="slider_value(this.value)" onchange="slider_value(this.value)"` .

Use both for full compatibility, since `oninput` is not supported in IE10.

Small example here, to get you started:
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ewBNGj

Notice that the function that sets the day/days string ( `value_name()` ) is called from within the `slider_value()` function.

Comment: You are welcome. You can further improve the code with descriptive method names, so keep an eye on that too. Happy coding.

Answer (score 0):

No need for complex js calculations, you could easily do this with the `change` event. add event listener to the `input` and then add you logic there, checkout the snippet

```js
var el = document.getElementById('myRange');
el.addEventListener('change', function(event){
  var value = event.target.value;
  var _container = document.getElementById('demo');
  value == 1 ? _container.innerText = value+' Day' : _container.innerText = value+' Days'
})
```

```html
<label for="duration">
                Course Duration :
                <span id="demo"></span>
                <span id="dname"></span>
            </label>

            <div class="slidecontainer">

                <input type="range" min="1" max="15" value="1" class="slider" id="myRange">

            </div>
```

Comment: i'll try this as well. but i've never use listners in my coding since i'm somewhat beginner. Any recommend tutorials???

Comment: you can refer w3school. `eventListeners` will listen for change and update accordingly, you can also add `removeEventListeners` if you dont need to listen to their changes.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the formatting of the slider's text in a function

```
  function updateSlider(e) {
    if (parseInt(e.value) == 1) {
      output.innerHTML = parseInt(e.value) + " Day";
    } else {
      output.innerHTML = parseInt(e.value) + " Days";
    }
  }
```

This way you can call it once initially and populate the text properly. To update the contents of the slider as something changes add the **input** event listener and call this function from there.

Here's an example:

```js
var slider = document.getElementById("myRange");
var output = document.getElementById("demo");

slider.oninput = function(e) {
  updateSlider(e.target);
}

function updateSlider(e) {
  if (parseInt(e.value) == 1) {
    output.innerHTML = parseInt(e.value) + " Day";
  } else {
    output.innerHTML = parseInt(e.value) + " Days";
  }
}

updateSlider(slider);
```

```html
<label for="duration">
                Course Duration :
                <span id="demo"></span>
                <span id="dname"></span>
            </label>

<div class="slidecontainer">

  <input type="range" min="1" max="15" value="1" class="slider" id="myRange">

</div>
```